# Selective event listening on DOM elements

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have this HTML code

```
<ul id='something'>
    <li class="listItem"><span class="name">Somename1</span> <span class="number">4</span></li>
    <li class="listItem"><span class="name">Somename2</span> <span class="number">4</span></li>
    <li class="listItem"><span class="name">Somename3</span> <span class="number">4</span></li>
</ul>
```

I also have this JavaScript code that attaches an event listener to the `ul` tag like this

```
let itemList = document.getElementById('something')
itemList.addEventListener('click', event => {
    ....
})
```

I want to use event bubbling to access the `li` elements but the `span` elements always get the event in the browser. How do I disable the event listener on the `span` elements? How can I use conditional statement to access only the immediate child elements of the `ul` tag. Is there a better way to go about this than what I'm doing? Please I'm using pure JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) on the event's target to find the closest `<li>` parent element (or itself if the `li` is clicked directly):

```js
let itemList = document.getElementById('something')
itemList.addEventListener('click', event => {
  const li = event.target.closest('li');

  if (!li) return;

  console.log(li);
})
```

```html
<ul id='something'>
  <li class="listItem"><span class="name">Somename1</span> <span class="number">4</span></li>
  <li class="listItem"><span class="name">Somename2</span> <span class="number">4</span></li>
  <li class="listItem"><span class="name">Somename3</span> <span class="number">4</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use pointer-events css attribute to achieve this.

```
#something li>span {
  pointer-events: none
}
```

Comment: This method works but I'm concerned of its security. CSS can easily be manipulated in the browser.